# urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54805): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/b690bde405b447b7efc9ee7bbc

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

```
from linkedin_scraper import Person, actions
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

email = "\*\*"
password = "-"
actions.login(driver, email, password)

person1 = Person("profile-url1", driver=driver)
person2 = Person("profile-url2", driver=driver)

print(person1.scrape())
print(person2.scrape())
```

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54805): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/b690bde405b447b7efc9ee7bbc19fd0a/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('\<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001766BF10BD0\>: Failed to establish a new connection: \[WinError 10061\] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte'))
```

I am using a LinkedIn scraper to get profile data.
For one person it works fine, but as soon as I try to include a second one it crashes.

I tried deactivating my firewall which did not help.

Comment: What line does your code reach before showing this error?